# Cannot find NancyOwinHost

Tags: .net, owin, windows-authentication, nancy

I have a Nancy module like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Principal;
using Nancy;

public class StatusModule : NancyModule
{
    public StatusModule()
    {
        Get["/"] = _ =>
        {
            var env = ((IDictionary<string, object>) Context.Items[Nancy.Owin.NancyOwinHost.RequestEnvironmentKey]);
            var user = (IPrincipal) env["server.User"];
            return Response.AsJson(new {TimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("O"), Status = "OK"});
        };
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting a compilation failure that `NancyOwinHost` can't be found.  According to SymbolSource it should be a public class in the `Nancy.Owin` assembly; however the latest they have is 1.3.0 and I'm using 1.4.1.

Cracking open that assembly it does indeed look like it's not there

[image: DotPeek view of Nancy.Owin assembly]

Any advise?  I'm trying to implement WindowsAuthentication over Nancy.

Thanks

Dave

## Edit

I've tried rolling back to version 0.22.1 and the class is present now.  (Although it fails at runtime as now the assemblies don't match `Field not found: 'Nancy.Bootstrapper.NancyBootstrapperLocator.Bootstrapper'.`).

Answer (score 0):

A wee bit of digging and common sense and I figured out the magic words were:

```
var requestEnvironment = (IDictionary<string, object>) Context.Items["OWIN_REQUEST_ENVIRONMENT"];
var user = (IPrincipal) requestEnvironment["server.User"];
```